Interactive barchart in R using plotly
I would like to recreate my ggplot barchart with plotly to make it interactive. However, I'm not able to get the y axis to be my desired variable and instead get  the following error: Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) :
object 'genome_size_in_Mb' not found.
My data:
dput():
structure(list(Subgroups = c("Jessenii", "fluorescens", "fluorescens", 
"gessardii", "gessardii", "fragi", "fragi"), `Species Name + Strain` = c("Pseudomonas umsongensis", 
"Pseudomonas fluorescens", "Pseudomonas extremaustralis", "Pseudomonas sp.", 
"Pseudomonas fluorescens", "Pseudomonas psychrophila", "Pseudomonas taetrolens"
), Strain = c("GO16", "SBW25", "DSM17835", "Ag1", "R8", "HA4", 
"LMG2336"), `refseq assembly` = c("GCF_008824165.1", "GCF_000009225.2", 
"GCF_900102035.1", "GCF_000006765.1", "GCF_000297195.3", "GCF_000282975.1", 
"GCF_900104825.1"), genome_size_in_Mb = c(7.4, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 
7, 5.2, 4.9), `chromosome number` = c("2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"-", "-"), `GC content` = c(59, 60.5, 60.5, 66.5, 61, 56.5, 58
), `Number of CDS genes` = c(6441, 5974, 6000, 5572, 6307, 4666, 
4360), `Genes number` = c(6698, 6154, 6228, 6708, 6440, 4823, 
4507)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

The ggplot chart code:
ggplot(
  data = dba,
  aes(x = forcats::fct_inorder(Strain),
      y = genome_size_in_Mb,
      fill = Subgroups)
) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  labs(title = "Genome Sizes Across Strains", x = "Strain", y = "Genome Size in Mb")


Following Plotly's example online
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

fig1 <- dba
fig1 <- fig1 %>% count(Strain, Subgroups)
fig1 <- fig1 %>% plot_ly(x = ~Strain, y = ~n, color = ~Subgroups)

print(fig1)




library(plotly)

plot_ly(dba, x = ~forcats::fct_inorder(Strain),
        y = ~genome_size_in_Mb,
        color = ~Subgroups, 
        type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = "Genome Sizes Across Strains", x = 0.1), 
         xaxis = list(title = "Strain"), 
         yaxis = list(title = "Genome Size in Mb"), 
         legend = list(title =  list(text = "Subgroups"), y = 0.5))


Created on 2024-07-08 with reprex v2.0.2

There is a faster way to make your ggplot2 graphics interactive. Simply wrap the ggplot2 object in ggplotly() to turn it into an interactive graph like so:
gg <- ggplot(
  data = dba,
  aes(x = forcats::fct_inorder(Strain),
      y = genome_size_in_Mb,
      fill = Subgroups)
) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  labs(title = "Genome Sizes Across Strains", x = "Strain", y = "Genome Size in Mb")


ggplotly(gg)

Hope this helps!

That is perfect! Thank you so much (It wont let me upvote)

Glad it was the solution you were looking for. Please accept it as the answer so that other developers can benefit from it.
